# Dialog didn't show

Tags: android

I am trying to pop up a dialog when the user overwrite on a backup database so I wrote this code but it didn't work:

```
$if(backupDB.exists()){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getBaseContext());
    builder.setTitle("Backup database...");
    builder.setMessage("You have already backup the database, do you want to overwrite?");

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
           Intent i=new Intent(getBaseContext(),FinancialSecretary.class);
           finish();
           startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
}
```

what is wronge?

Comment: you forgot to call dialog.show(); at end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used for this code just try this out:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ActivityName.this);
```

And u whatever require for method implement and last one set to show dialog,

```
builder.show();
```

Comment: The first one is the solution, but the second it make no different. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Just add after your code:

```
dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you forgot to put show :) .

This is the code i like using, just fill it up with what you need, and add the title and what else you need:

new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(pozadina).setPositiveButton("Ok", new OnClickListener () {

```
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


        }


    }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


        }
    }).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1) When create dialog, you cannot use baseContext(), you should use activity:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CurrentActivity.this);
```

2) You forgot to call dialog.show().