# AlertDialog Crashes when cast on second time

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm trying to use an alertdialog to recieve data from the user, the first time I use it, there is no problem, but if I cast the alertdialog a second time the application crashes.

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        final LinearLayout marco=new LinearLayout(this);
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        final EditText input2 = new EditText(this);
        final TextView nom=new TextView(this);
        nom.setText("Nombre:");
        final TextView ap=new TextView(this);
        ap.setText("Apellido:");
        input.setWidth(500);
        input2.setWidth(500);
        ((LinearLayout)marco).addView(nom);
        ((LinearLayout)marco).addView(input);
        ((LinearLayout)marco).addView(ap);
        ((LinearLayout)marco).addView(input2);
        alert.setTitle("Introduce Datos:");
        marco.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        alert.setView(marco);
        alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                String value = input.getText().toString().trim();
                String value2 = input2.getText().toString().trim();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), value, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String nombre=value,apellido=value2;
            db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Usuarios (codigo, nombre, apellido) " +
                        "VALUES (" + codigo + ", '" + nombre +"','"+apellido+"')");
                codigo++;
                RellenarSpinner(db);

            }
        });
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                dialog.cancel();
                ((AlertDialog.Builder) alert).setView(marco);
            }
        });
final Button alta=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnAlta);
alta.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                alert.show();
            }});
```

Comment: post your logcat or debug to find out which line cause your app to crash

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child alredy has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i started working with alertdialogs. Try making a global variable public AlertDialog myAlert;  and then use this variable when making your dialog appear. Or just go with the code:  new AlertDialog.Builder.set....set.(...).show();     ...

Comment: here is a post on stack,you got a working code you can use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645605/dialog-didnt-show/13645725#comment18749719_13645725